# Get 'native' commits on a branch

Tags: git, git-merge, git-log

I want to get only 'native' commits on a branch. It means:

- direct commits to the branch;
- merge commits;

I do not want to get commits that came from a merged branch - only merge commits itself. How can I do this with `git log`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `git log --first-parent` to only include the *left* side of merge commits, i.e. the *first parent*. That will exclude any commits that got merged in from other branches, since those would be on the *right* side of merge commits.

From the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

> **--first-parent**
>   Follow only the first parent commit upon seeing a merge commit. This
>   option can give a better overview when viewing the evolution of a
>   particular topic branch, because merges into a topic branch tend to be
>   only about adjusting to updated upstream from time to time, and this
>   option allows you to ignore the individual commits brought in to your
>   history by such a merge. Cannot be combined with --bisect.